# How to do a full oracle database export or import yet exclude one tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, impdp, expdp

I'm working on creating a scheduled task to do a weekly refresh of an Oracle 11g database from production to test. I want to do a full export / import with the exception of one tablespace named PERFSTAT which we use in production with stats pack, but don't really need in test.

Here is my current export command

```
EXPDP system/password@instance FULL=Y DIRECTORY=TRPROD_EXPORT DUMPFILE=TRPROD_FULL_EXPORT.DMP LOGFILE=TRPROD_FULL_EXPORT.LOG COMPRESSION=all
```

When I tested the import, i got the following error

```
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'G:\ORACLE\ORADATA\TRPROD\PERFSTAT01.DBF'
ORA-27038: created file already exists
OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLESPACE "PERFSTAT" DATAFILE 'G:\ORACLE\ORADATA\TRPROD\PERFSTAT01.DBF' SIZE 209715200 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10485760 MAXSIZE 2146435072 LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPAC
```

I've tried adding EXCLUDE=TABLESPACE:"='PERFSTAT'" to the EXPDP command to try and exclude that tablespace, but I gave me a syntax error, so I'm wondering what the correct way to do a full refresh of our test database would be yet exclude this one specific tablespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parameter file as shown below.

```
[oracle@oratestprod fra]$ cat test.par
DIRECTORY=TRPROD_EXPORT
FULL=Y 
DUMPFILE=TRPROD_FULL_EXPORT.DMP 
LOGFILE=TRPROD_FULL_EXPORT.LOG 
COMPRESSION=all
exclude=tablespace:"IN ('PERFSTAT')"
```

And run as shown below.

```
[oracle@oratestprod fra]$ expdp system parfile=test.par
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess when I was trying to run in all in one line certain quote characters would have needed to be escaped. I've switched to using the par file an this works great now.